# Deploy app.R in a server without index.html

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to access a Shiny app, `app.R` via web. In which directory does the `app.R` need to be stored?

Shiny's default sample apps have their own directories, e.g., `/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps/hello`. Inside the directory are `ui.R` and `server.R` files. The app is linked in `index.html` with `<iframe src="./sample-apps/hello/"`. I deleted `ui.R` and `server.R` files in `hello/` directory and place my `app.R` file there. But I'm now getting error.

Is it possible to run the app without an `index.html` file? If index.html is must, how do I link the app? I'm perfectly file RStudio's output when `app.R` is run. No fancy layout is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For normal webservers: one can't just place the .R file on a server, one actually has to execute it using R. When using a webserver with other content, you can then use proxying (ProxyPass in Apache) to deliver contents, and possibly embed it.

For shiny-server, I'm not sure. It seems to follow the server.R / ui.R pattern. an existing app.R could be refactored like this: ssume you have an app.R with `something();shinyApp(ui = verticalLayout(...), server=function(input, output){...})`, you could refactor into a server.R with `something(); server <- function(input, output){...}` and a ui.R with `ui <- verficalLayout(...)`. For the sake of clarity, I put the server / ui assignment on the very bottom of the file.

Comment: sorry, I've overlooked you're already using shiny-server. In that case I'm sorry, I don't know for sure. Maybe splitting up app.R could do the trick...

Comment: I've a few statements at the beginning (outside `ui` and and `server` blocks). I'm not sure how to splitl.

Comment: then at least I get chance to provide you with some answer: assume you have an app.R with ```something();shinyApp(ui = verticalLayout(...), server=function(input, output){...})```, you could refactor into a server.R with ```something(); server <- function(input, output){...}``` and a ui.R with ```ui <- verficalLayout(...)```